# datepicker value is blank when disabled, jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm fairly new to jQuery. I have a Jquery datepicker in a user control. I have added a "disable" property to the datepicker. Whenever I save the page(having this usercontrol) the datepicker with disable set to true is empty. All other datepickers save fine.

Here is my code.

ASPX

< USERCONTROL:DATEPICKER id="dpBirthDate" startyear="1980" runat="server" Disable=true>

ASCX
 < input type="text"  size="8" runat="server" id="txtDate" name="txtDate" onblur="ValidateForm(this.id);" />

ASCX Code Behind

```
Public Property Disable() As Boolean
        Get
           Return (txtDate.Disabled = True)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal bValue As Boolean)

            If (bValue = True) Then
                txtDate.Attributes.Add("Disabled", "True")
            Else
                txtDate.Attributes.Remove("Disabled")
            End If

        End Set


    End Property
```

My Jquery

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    $("input[id$=txtDate]").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImage: '<%=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("BASE_DIRECTORY")%>/Images/el-calendar.gif', buttonImageOnly: true });
    $("input[id$=txtDate]").mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: " " });


    //Disable datepicker if "disable=true"
    $("input[id$=txtDate]").each(function() {

    if ($("input[id$=" + this.id + "]").attr("Disabled") == "True") {          
            $("input[id$=" + this.id + "]").datepicker("disable");               
        }
        else if ($("input[id$=" + this.id + "]").attr("Disabled") == "False") {
            $("input[id$=" + this.id + "]").datepicker("enable");
        }

    });


});
```

I am sorry, I am not sure how to format the code here. I apologies for the cluttered code.
Can anybody tell me why the datepicker value is empty when it is disabled but works fine otherwise?
Thanks is advance.

Comment: This is an HTML thing--disabled form fields don't get sent to the server by the browser; use read-only instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but try using READONLY instead of DISABLED?

Answer (score 0):

I think also using readonly property to true, does not change the intial value in postback

if are insist to use it by readonly property you will change override of get Text
like this

```
public override string Text
{
    get
    {
        if (!base.ReadOnly)
            return base.Text;

        string s = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params[this.UniqueID];
        if (s == null)
            return base.Text;
        else
        {
            base.Text = s;
            return s;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        base.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
$('input:checkbox[name=cmpltInd]').change(function () {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#efctDt').attr('readonly', true).datepicker("option", "showOn", "off");
   }
   else {
      $('#efctDt').attr('readonly', false).datepicker("option", "showOn", "focus");
   }
});
if ( ($('input:checkbox[name=cmpltInd]') != "undefined") && ($('input:checkbox[name=cmpltInd]').prop("checked")== true)) {
     $('#efctDt').attr('readonly', true).datepicker("option", "showOn", "off");
 }
```